# Webpack inject scripts to index html file in production

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a index html file and i need to inject in production ENV additional scripts. with gulp i can do this with plugin like gulp inject, How can i do this with webpack?

For example:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
// I want this script only in the production index html file
<script src="script2.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use gulp-inject-webpack plugin

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject-webpack-plugin